# OSX - ERROR: Error installing cocoapods

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods

How to fix it?

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: minitest-5.9.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-5.9.1
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.2
Fetching: activesupport-5.0.0.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

EDIT:

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works.

```
$ uname -a
Darwin MACMACMAC 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
Fetching: activesupport-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for activesupport-4.2.6
unable to convert "\x84" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat, skipping
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-4.2.6
1 gem installed

$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Fetching: nap-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed nap-1.1.0
Fetching: fuzzy_match-2.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Fetching: cocoapods-core-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.0.1
Fetching: claide-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed claide-1.0.1
Fetching: cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.1
Fetching: cocoapods-downloader-1.1.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-1.1.1
Fetching: cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-search-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-search-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-stats-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-stats-1.0.0
Fetching: netrc-0.7.8.gem (100%)
Successfully installed netrc-0.7.8
Fetching: cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-try-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-try-1.1.0
Fetching: molinillo-0.4.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed molinillo-0.4.5
Fetching: colored-1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed colored-1.2
Fetching: xcodeproj-1.3.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed xcodeproj-1.3.2
Fetching: escape-0.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed escape-0.0.4
Fetching: fourflusher-0.3.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed fourflusher-0.3.2
Fetching: cocoapods-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.0.1
Parsing documentation for nap-1.1.0
Installing ri documentation for nap-1.1.0
Parsing documentation for fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Installing ri documentation for fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-core-1.0.1
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-core-1.0.1
Parsing documentation for claide-1.0.1
Installing ri documentation for claide-1.0.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.1
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-downloader-1.1.1
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-downloader-1.1.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-search-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-search-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-stats-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-stats-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for netrc-0.7.8
Installing ri documentation for netrc-0.7.8
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-try-1.1.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-try-1.1.0
Parsing documentation for molinillo-0.4.5
Installing ri documentation for molinillo-0.4.5
Parsing documentation for colored-1.2
Installing ri documentation for colored-1.2
Parsing documentation for xcodeproj-1.3.2
Installing ri documentation for xcodeproj-1.3.2
Parsing documentation for escape-0.0.4
Installing ri documentation for escape-0.0.4
Parsing documentation for fourflusher-0.3.2
Installing ri documentation for fourflusher-0.3.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.0.1
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-1.0.1
18 gems installed
```